# Implement Treeset with custom sorting functionality

Tags: java, arrays, collections, set, comparator

I am trying to implement treeset with custom sorting functionality. I have passed comparator object which hold sorting logic.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class MySetWithCompr {

    public static void main(String a[]){

        TreeSet<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(new MyComp());
        ts.add("Test1");
        ts.add("Test2");
        ts.add("Test3");
        ts.add("Test4");
        System.out.println(ts);
    }
}

class MyComp implements Comparator<String>{

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2);
    }

}
```

The above program is giving me the below output

```
[Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4]
```

Please suggest how to implement comparator logic so that the result would be reverse

```
Expected Result : [Test4, Test3, Test2, Test1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to desc ordering there are two ways :

First :

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str2.compareTo(str1);
    }
}
```

Second :

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return -1 * str1.compareTo(str2);
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is no need for multiplication. It can just be `- str1.compareTo(str2)`.

Comment: Yes it's true but it's just a matter of syntax witch rely on eachones preferences

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Java 8 you can simply write:

```
Set<String> ts = new TreeSet<>(new MyComp().reversed());
```

There is the same functionality before Java 8 (since Java 5):

```
Set<String> ts = new TreeSet<String>(Collections.reverseOrder(new MyComp()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        return str2.compareTo(str1);
    }

}
```